# inserting from erlang into cassandra

Tags: erlang, cassandra, thrift

I am trying to insert something into cassandra 0.7.6 from Erlang R14B02 (through thrift 0.6.1)

I am doing the following:

1. Read record definitions

   rr(cassandra_types).
2. Connect to cassandra

   {ok, C}=thrift_client_util:new("localhost", 9160, cassandra_thrift,[{strict_read, false}, {strict_write, false}, {framed, true}]).
3. Try to insert a value (timestamp=1, 2=Quorum)

   Reply1 = thrift_client:call(C, 'insert', ["existing_keyspace", "new_key",#columnPath{column_family = "existing_column_family", column = "existing_column"}, "new_value",1,2]).

But nr3 gives me a bad_args error (1 and 2 work perfectly). What would be the right arguments?

Comment: Ups, I forgot, sorry for that, edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What API information there is for unsupported languages is largely in their [Cassandra Thrift API documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API).

In Cassandra 0.7, you don't supply the keyspace for most operations, so `insert` just takes `[Key, ColumnPath, Column, ConsistencyLevel]`. You need to call `set_keyspace` before attempting the insert. The insert in erlang would be

```
Reply1 = thrift_client:call(C, 'insert',
                            [SomeKey,
                             #columnPath{column_family = "existing_column_family",
                                         column = "existing_column"},
                             #column{name="existing_column",
                                     value="new_value",timestamp=1},
                             ?cassandra_ConsistencyLevel_QUORUM]).
```

Your example is missing the row key for the insert I think too.

As an aside, make sure you always update the value of C - it changes after every thrift_client call.

?cassandra_ConsistencyLevel_QUORUM is 2 from memory.

Comment: I'm still getting bad_Args... in your call the column name is given twice, is that right?. My row key was "new_key"

Comment: In case someone got the same problem, this is what worked for me: {C22,_} = thrift_client:call(C21,'insert',["test_key",#columnParent{column_family="exiting_CF"},#column{name="exiting_Column",value="new_val",timestamp=1},2]).

Comment: BTW. the best documentation for erlang/thrift/cassandra is the generated code for erlang. At least you get to see what functions you have.

Answer (score 0):

This might help, although there is no erlang-specific code: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ThriftExamples