# creating Keyspace

Tags: erlang, cassandra, thrift

I am trying to access cassandra from erlang, as a test I am trying to create a new keyspace. I do it as follows:

**1> rr(cassandra_thrift).**

```
[authenticationException,authenticationRequest,
 authorizationException,cfDef,column,columnDef,
 columnOrSuperColumn,columnParent,columnPath,counterColumn,
 counterSuperColumn,cqlMetadata,cqlResult,cqlRow,deletion,
 endpointDetails,indexClause,indexExpression,
 invalidRequestException,keyCount,keyRange,keySlice,ksDef,
 mutation,notFoundException,schemaDisagreementException,
 slicePredicate,sliceRange,superColumn|...]
```

**2> {ok,C1}=thrift_client_util:new("127.0.0.1",9160,thrift_cassandra,[]).**

```
{ok,{tclient,thrift_cassandra,
        {protocol,thrift_binary_protocol,
            {binary_protocol,
                {transport,thrift_buffered_transport,
                    {buffered_transport,
                        {transport,thrift_socket_transport,
                            {data,#Port<0.593>,infinity}},
                        []}},
                true,true}},
        0}}
```

**3> Reply1=thrift_client:call(C1,set_keyspace,["Test_KS"]).**

```
** exception exit: undef
     in function  thrift_cassandra:function_info/2
        called as thrift_cassandra:function_info(set_keyspace,params_type)
     in call from thrift_client:send_function_call/3 (thrift_client.erl, line 70)
     in call from thrift_client:call/3 (thrift_client.erl, line 40)
```

Am I doing something wrong, or does my erlang not have access to the cassandra functions? How can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372654/inserting-from-erlang-into-cassandra

Comment: Start from thrift_client:module_info() to figure out if you have right version and the function har right arity.

Comment: The arity seems to be right: {exports,[{call,3},{send_call,3},{close,1},{module_info,0},{module_info,1},{new,2}]}

Comment: It seems that thrift_client is calling the module thrift_cassandra, but I only have the module called cassandra_thrift. Any1 knows how to solve this? or what went wrong? Just renaming is probably not a good idea..

Comment: Btw. using Cassandra 1.0.7 with thrift 0.6.0 and erlang r15B on openSUSE 12.1

Comment: @2> it sould have been cassandra_thrift not thrift_cassandra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use https://github.com/ostinelli/erlcassa over raw Thrift from Erlang.

Comment: "This is an alpha library which should not be used in production." My system is intended for use in production at a later time ;) but thanks for pointing it out, I will be waiting for the 1.0 version =)

Comment: Well, on the other hand, I prefeer to use a client than thrift for production. Did anyone try it out yet?